# bash script to log/print all connections in the last N seconds

Tags: bash, file, networking, grep, netstat

I'd like to: run a script in background that prints every X seconds something like:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:5555          localhost:47824         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:47824         localhost:5555          ESTABLISHED
```

even if the connection has been already closed, so I will see what connections has been opened (does not matter if closed or still open)in that timespan.

I did this to tail the output to a temp file:

```
#!/bin/sh


    #dump netstat result of established connections to a temp file
    (netstat -c | grep --line-buffered ESTABLISHED >> 1.tmp &)


while true
do
    #copy the file with the dump and flush it, something like log rotation
    #THE PROBLEM IS HERE######
    cp 1.tmp 2.tmp && rm 1.tmp
    ##########################

    #add a prefix on each line to reconize the logs
    sed -i -e 's/^/Connections: /' 2.tmp

    #print the logs to standard output, only one entry for each connection
    cat 2.tmp | uniq


    sleep 10
done
```

Obviously this is not the right way, as the deletion of the file will kill the netstat process, I thought that it would just create another new file.

I can do something with the `head` command on netstat to block it every X lines and change file, but I'm not sure if this will cause to loose some info on a very fast connection/disconnection

Any other way to have a reliable way to log connections are welcome, keep in mind I don't have root privileges, but I only need to know connections made by the user that also runs this script so is fine.

EDIT: I am not happy with the actual solution I just posted, as netstat runs by default every second, and some connections can be way more rapid, and I need a way to get ALL outbound connections made from the user running this script (remember, no root privileges). At the moment I'm trying `netstat -c 0.1` but I still cannot trust it

Comment: you can just remove content of 1.tmp. I would do it like this `cat 1.tmp > 2.tmp && > 1.tmp` , it will redirect content of 1.tmp to 2.tmp and if it will be successfull it will remove content of 1.tmp

Answer (score 2):

This is the working script with the suggestion from @vlp plus a fix to get unique results, as only `uniq`was not enough, I need to sort them to get unique lines.

```
#!/bin/sh


    #dump netstat result of established connections to a temp file
    (netstat -c | grep --line-buffered ESTABLISHED >> 1.tmp &)


while true
do
    #redirect content of 1.tmp to 2.tmp and remove it from 1.tmp
    cat 1.tmp > 2.tmp && > 1.tmp


    #add a prefix on each line to reconize the logs
    sed -i -e 's/^/Connections: /' 2.tmp

    #print the logs to standard output, only one entry for each connection
    cat 2.tmp | sort -u

    #delete the file
    rm 2.tmp

    sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach, you might want to consider investigating whether you can insert `iptables` rules to log connection establishment, and have your script parse the resulting logs.  This may require more work, but should report short-lived connections, and could (if you want) log refused connections and more.

Comment: Yes, it would be a better solution for more detailed info, but is not possible without root privileges (I don't ever have privileges, not only for the actual logging script)